# Emacs hashtag bracket(#[]) notation

Tags: projectile, helm-projectile

When choosing a project using `helm-projectile-switch-project` one can type C-d to run dired on that project root directory.

Running `describe-key` on `C-d` returns the following function:

`#[nil "\300\301!\207" [helm-exit-and-execute-action dired]
2 nil nil]`

Any pointers on where I can read about on how to make sense of this notation? This looks like a "printed notation", yet I'm unable to find it in the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the printed notation of compiled emacs lisp byte-code, you can read more about it [in the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Byte-Compilation.html#Byte-Compilation).

[This post will probably be more helpful](http://nullprogram.com/blog/2014/01/04/) with understanding what is represented in the vectors you see.